# Performance difference between Select count(ID) and Select count(*)

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, select, count

There are two queries below which return count of ID column excluding NULL values 
and second query will return the count of all the rows from the table including NULL rows.

```
select COUNT(ID) from TableName  

select COUNT(*) from TableName
```

My Confusion :
Is there any performance difference ?

Comment: Logic would indicate the test for NULL would slow things down - difference is probably in milliseconds unless you have millions of records.

Comment: @Kamil: Though similar, it's not the same question. Your link has to do with 3 different ways of expressing a query that will generate the exact same results. In this case, the 2 queries don't return the same results. Based on OP's description, `ID` is nullable, which is very weird though. I hope OP's description is correct.

Comment: What is the definition of `TableName`? Is `ID` really nullable as you're suggesting? Odd name if it is.  What indexes do you have?

Comment: You said: *including NULL rows*.. what do you mean exactly?  Is it possible that you're only showing us a partial query?  Are you actually talking about a query with a left join?

Comment: It is a testing Table having single Null able column. Based on the answer, I would select one of the option on production environment

Comment: @RoopBasant I don't see any difference. They both get identical query plans.

Answer (score 1):

> TL/DR: Plans might not be the same, you should test on appropriate
>   data and make sure you have the correct indexes and then choose the best solution based on your investigations.

The query plans might not be the same depending on the indexing and the nullability of the column which is used in the COUNT function.

In the following example I create a table and fill it with one million rows.
All the columns have been indexed except column 'b'.

The conclusion is that some of these queries do result in the same execution plan but most of them are different.

This was tested on SQL Server 2014, I do not have access to an instance of 2012 at this moment. You should test this yourself to figure out the best solution.

```
create table t1(id bigint identity, 
                dt datetime2(7) not null default(sysdatetime()), 
                a char(800) null, 
                b char(800) null,
                c char(800) null);

-- We will use these 4 indexes. Only column 'b' does not have any supporting index on it.
alter table t1 add constraint [pk_t1]  primary key NONCLUSTERED (id);
create clustered index cix_dt on t1(dt);
create nonclustered index ix_a on t1(a);
create nonclustered index ix_c on t1(c);

insert into T1 (a, b, c) 
select top 1000000 
    a = case when low = 1 then null else left(REPLICATE(newid(), low), 800) end, 
    b = case when low between 1 and 10 then null else left(REPLICATE(newid(), 800-low), 800) end,
    c = case when low between 1 and 192 then null else left(REPLICATE(newid(), 800-low), 800) end
from master..spt_values 
cross join (select 1 from master..spt_values) m(ock)
where type = 'p';


checkpoint;

-- All rows, no matter if any columns are null or not
-- Uses primary key index
select count(*) from t1;

-- All not null, 
-- Uses primary key index
select count(id) from t1;

-- Some values of 'a' are null
-- Uses the index on 'a'
select count(a) from t1;

-- Some values of b are null
-- Uses the clustered index
select count(b) from t1;

-- No values of dt are null and the table have a clustered index on 'dt'
-- Uses primary key index and not the clustered index as one could expect.
select count(dt) from t1;

-- Most values of c are null
-- Uses the index on c
select count(c) from t1;
```

[image: Different select count results]

Now what would happen if we were more explicit in what we wanted our count to do? If we tell the query planner that we want to get only rows which have not null, will that change anything?

```
-- Homework!
-- What happens if we explicitly count only rows where the column is not null? What if we add a filtered index to support this query?
-- Hint: It will once again be different than the other queries.
create index ix_c2 on t1(c) where c is not null;
select count(*) from t1 where c is not null;
```